# use background-color until background-image is loaded

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for a div.

I need the background to be a different colour other than white until the background image is loaded.

I can not use a background color on a container div, as my background image has transparency and I want to see page content underneath.

is there a way to have a background color which loads instantly, and then when the background image is loaded use that? I know I could do it with JS but is there any fallback method I can use with just css/ html?

Comment: is this kind of feature so serious to need a pure CSS solution? This can be considered as an advanced feature, so if the client has no script enabled, it does not matter much.

Comment: Why not use some image preloader?

Comment: The only thing that resembles this, with pure CSS would be to use an infinite CSS animation for the background color. But this is hacky and will not work on older browsers.

Comment: @Andrei the problem is the time of loading is very very various among clients depending on the network speed, the server's response at the loading time, ... so I'm sure we can't have any pure CSS solution for this kind of dynamic styling.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said that it "resembles". If you take in consideration the animation time, in a high percentage of cases, it could work.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply stack the two CSS rules.

```
background-color: #000;
background-image: url("...");
```

The background color will display until the image is loaded.

Comment: The problem is the background-image has some transparent background, so after it's loaded, the background-color is still shown through the transparent background of the background-image, which is not the OP wants.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai In that case, a purely CSS solution is not the way to go. You can easily accomplish this with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely against Javascript for whatever reason, you can create an effect that **mimics** what you would obtain with Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Qk5K/5/

```
div {
    background : url(http://www.st.hirosaki-u.ac.jp/~shimpei/GPS/GPSCMC/images/sphere-transparent.png);
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
}

.container:before{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    content:"";
    background:#333;
    -webkit-animation: fade-out 99999s 1 linear; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    fade-out 99999s 1 linear; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      fade-out 99999s 1 linear; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         fade-out 99999s 1 linear; /* IE 10+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  0.002% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-out {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  0.002% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes fade-out {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  0.002% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade-out {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  0.002% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

What this does is:

- add a block element above your image, with your desired background.
- fade that background after little time (you have to find the right amount that works for your content).
- keep the background faded with infinite time.

The down side of this as you probably noticed is that you can't predict the exact time. For some, the image would load, for others it may still have a little bit till it loaded.

You can also adjust do fade-out time, depending on browser. If someone access the website with IE8 for example, you can add a higher fade-out time.

Also, a `delay` can be added to the animation, to only start it after some time.